# Am I allowed get a copy/transcript/recording of New Zealand Student Visa interview?

Tags: immigration, student-visa, new-zealand, refusal, interview

I applied for a New Zealand Student Visa in April this year. I had to attend a Telephone Interview taken by an New Zealand immigration officer. Some days after that, I got a refusal letter.

Is it possible to get a copy/recording/transcript of the telephone interview?

Please reply asap. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is there anyone who can respond?

Comment: Maybe, but they're not necessarily checking this website hourly for your convenience. Why don't you contact the authorities directly to ask?

Comment: Im not a government employee, but a gut feeling is no, you can't. You can be refused an entry into any country and i don't think that the country has got obligations to explain itself, as long as it's formally presented you with a refusal letter. You also dont mention anything about your background, nationality etc, which may have played a role.

Comment: so far I know, in case of UK visa interview (video conference), applicants are allowed to have a transcript (the interview in written form or audio/video form) upon request.

Answer (score 1):

As with any visa application in any country, being declined can be based on many factors. Your letter from [Immigration New Zealand](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/assist-migrants-and-students/assist-students/student-visa-info) would advise you of the reasons, and what to do next, including any right you have to appeal, review, or access its records (e.g., of your interview).

It would also contain a copy of the immigration instructions which you may not have met. Should you still disagree, or decide it's best to remedy any shortcomings and reapply, you may wish to consult an adviser. By law, any person that gives you immigration advice about New Zealand must be licensed by the [Immigration Advisers Authority.](http://www.iaa.govt.nz/)

Answer (score -1):

Usually telephone interview is not recorded but face to face interview at the Immigration NZ branch are recorded. Telephone interview are usually recorded by the officer as notes made at the time and gets entered into Immigration New Zealand AMS notes systems. It is quite unfair that when you make official information request with OIA, they will tell you it is not recorded.

In criminal court, evidence without other support evidence is not admissable however Immigration New Zealand officers has discretionary power to decline you.

Comment: I'm a lawyer in the US. I have never heard of a legal system where "evidence without other support evidence" is not admissible." To the contrary — as the California jury instruction has it — "The testimony of one witness can prove any fact." Some exceptions exist (proof grounded in circumstantial evidence, evidence given by a co-conspirator, etc.) but the absolute statement presented in this answer is not correct. Downvoted.